# Not getting all links from page

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am trying to get all links from page but not getting all links. I am using selenium web driver.

My code is below :

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://www.digit.in");
    java.util.List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    System.out.println(links.size());
    System.out.println(links);

    } }
```

How can I get all links from page?

Comment: Are you getting some, but not all links, or no links at all? Are you able to find other elements?

Comment: **Try This** System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.tagName("a")).getSize());

Comment: This is not printing all elements ,anyone know how to scroll all elements and get all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be lot of links as result so you must put loop when getting result , See update code below :

```
   public static void main(String[] args){

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://www.digit.in");
    java.util.List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    System.out.println(links.size());

    for (int i=0;i<=links.size()-1;i=i+1)

    {

        System.out.println(links.get(i).getText());


    }
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are actually getting all the links from the page I think what you are seeing is that when you go to print them out you are getting the String representation of the `List<WebElement> collection`.  To actually see each of the links you need to iterate through the list.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://www.digit.in");
    java.util.List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    System.out.println(links.size());
    for(WebElement link : links)
        {
            System.out.println(link);
        }

    } 
}
```

This particular format will only give you the string representation of each WebElement object.

The **output** looks something like this:

```
284
[[RemoteWebDriver: firefox on XP (ef74c088-1406-44e8-a40e-ec290ea4c44a)] -> tag name: a]
[[RemoteWebDriver: firefox on XP (ef74c088-1406-44e8-a40e-ec290ea4c44a)] -> tag name: a]
[[RemoteWebDriver: firefox on XP (ef74c088-1406-44e8-a40e-ec290ea4c44a)] -> tag name: a]
[[RemoteWebDriver: firefox on XP (ef74c088-1406-44e8-a40e-ec290ea4c44a)] -> tag name: a]
[[RemoteWebDriver: firefox on XP (ef74c088-1406-44e8-a40e-ec290ea4c44a)] -> tag name: a]
[[RemoteWebDriver: firefox on XP (ef74c088-1406-44e8-a40e-ec290ea4c44a)] -> tag name: a]
....
```

If you want to get the say the href attribute of the WebElement you can use this instead;

```
System.out.println(link.getAttribute("href"));
```